# Where do I learn more about Jonas Albrecht?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

W20 starts with a glorious little comic, in which a white-haired guy called Albrecht with a huge Klaive rescues a cub. Then in the Character Generation example, we learn Jonas Albrecht's setup for when *he* was just a cub. It's the same person: Jonas Albrect, the Rank 6 Silver Fang "King of Werewolves", Packmate of Mari Cabrah, Black Fury. She's *also* in that comic from the start. She's the wolfish woman that Albrecht quipped to after being quite battered from a Wyrm-beast while being held on the feet by some guy called Evan.

But that's about it. Or rather, that is actually **more** than is in the book about one of the most iconic characters of Werewolf! Because we don't actually learn that Jonas Albrecht is a Rank 6 and "King of Werewolves". It's just... common knowledge among long-time players who he is.

Now, which publications describe some of the deeds of Jonas Albrecht and his exploits, like when he put on that crown that burned a wyrm beast's head to mush?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A Mix of Rulebooks and Novels Will Give You the Full Picture

While various rulebooks have sprinkled in more lore over the years, I'd recommend the Rage tie-in novel *"The Silver Crown"* which details when Jonas Albrecht locates the lost Silver Crown and claims the Silver Fangs' throne.

*"Last Battle"* shows Jonas during the Time of Judgement from the perspective of other characters and ties into the *"Apocalypse"* scenario book.

*"Silver Fangs Tribebook"* and *"Tribebook: Silver Fangs Revised"* have sections that talk about Jonas.

*Rage: Warriors of the Apocalypse* contains a profile for Lord Albrecht, including a short history paragraph.

All of these are available as pdfs (and possibly Print on Demand) through DriveThruRPG

Comment: That *silver crown* is the very one I roughly indicated in the OP I guess